# Bullet and numbering not working on soft enter and was working in previous version

Tags: tinymce

If we add content with shift+enter  and apply bullet and numbering it only applies to the first line.

I am using Version: `5.0.5 (2019-05-09)`

But in the previous version of `TinyMCE` it's not behaving the same,

```
majorVersion : '3',

minorVersion : '5.8',

releaseDate : '2012-11-20'
```

In the above version even if we pressed `shift + enter ( soft enter )` bullet and numbering are working. It's creating a li for each br

Answer (score 0):

In my testing of 3.5.8 using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> creates a `<br>` tag and does not create a new `<li>` element.  Pressing the regular <kbd>Enter</kbd> key does cause a new new `<li>` element to be created.

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/ULgaab

The behavior you are describing is (regardless of TinyMCE version) the expected behavior.  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> creates a `<br>` which would note create a new list element.

Comment: No. If you can check in your fiddle also its working.

Step

test <shift +enter>
test <shift +enter>
test <shift +enter>


Now select all the above the line and apply bullet. It will apply to all. But in new version it is not working